# Laravel changing parameters for store controller function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a master/detail view where a modal window has to send the master id  to the store function, so I can create a new detail record. It display the error "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\HorarioPeriodicosController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected"

This is the code of the store function at the controllers file

```
public function store( Request $request,$idGrupo )
{
    //
    dd($idGrupo);
    if ($idGrupo)
    {
        dd($idGrupo);
        $horarioPeriodicos = horarioPeriodicos::create(
            [   'idGrupo'=>$idGrupo,
                'intDia'=>$request->input('intDia'),
                'timHoraInicio'=>$request->input('timHoraInicio'),
                'timHoraFin'=>$request->input('timHoraFin')
            ]
        );

        if($horarioPeriodicos)
        {

            dd($horarioPeriodicos);
            return back()->withInput()->with('success','El horario se creó correctamente');
        }
    }


}
```

I'm trying this at my view to call the function store

```
<form action="{{ route('horarioperiodicos.store',[$grupo->idGrupo]) }}" method="post">

                    {{ csrf_field() }}
```

But then I get the error menctioned.

I suppose I have to add a new route where I use two parameters, but I don't se how to do that the way I have been reading.

My routes files is simply

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    Route::resource('lockers','LockersController');
    Route::resource('escuelas','EscuelasController');
    Route::resource('grupos','GruposController');
    Route::resource('horarioperiodicos','HorarioPeriodicosController');
```

This I'll use this matter again with destroy to send parent details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
<form action="{{ route('horarioperiodicos.store') }}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="groupID" name="groupID">
```

now in your view in the section of script you assign the id and send it from the request

```
<script>
 $('#groupID').val({{$grupo->idGrupo}});
</script
```

in your `controller put dd($request->groupID);`

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had try that, the problem is that idGrupo is always null, my URL   is this http://localhost:81/gymmgr/public/horarioperiodicos?2. I'm able to see it with a dd(idGrupo) at store.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It didn't work with javascript, actually I used <input type="hidden" id="groupID" name="groupID" value= {{ $grupo->idGrupo }} >